# Arduino AES library

Tags: encryption, authentication, aes, android

I am using [this Arduino library](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=88890.0) and [this Android library](https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto) to:

1. Create random string in Arduino
2. Pass it to Android to encrypt with AES and shared secret key
3. Pass back to Arduino to decrypt with AES and shared secret key
4. Verify that original random string matches decrypted string

I'm am using AES 128bit in both devices and CBC and can get them to encrypt and decrypt their own strings, but I'm having trouble tying them together. I've got a few questions that will hopefully help:

1. How do the "blocks" in the Arduino code relate to the Android
   implementation?
2. From what I've read, to decrypt the cipher text on the Arduino from
   Android I will need to send, the cipher text, the IV, and the PBE
   iteration count. Is that correct and everything?
3. Android code takes my key and uses a bunch of SecretKeys functions
   on it to I think randomize it and make it more secure. If I'm having
   to store the key on the Arduino, do I need to even bother with this?
4. Where is the PBE iteration count in the Arduino code? I don't really
   see anything in the library. Do I need to implement that myself? I
   saw in the "test_vectors" example of the library a section that had
   the following bit of code. Is this the iteration?

   ```
   for (int j = 0 ; j < 1000 ; j++)
   {
       succ = aes.encrypt (plain, cipher) ;
       aes.copy_n_bytes (plain, cipher, 16) ;
   }
   ```

Comment: This is more of a code-level question. You'll need to ask people with closer access to the library.

Comment: You might want to try asking this question on the Arduino Stack Exchange: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/